# Do this for me and then we'll be even

Tags: translation

I'm trying to convey "If you do x, we'll call it even."

So my sentence is:

> 我们可以互相学习，我教你滑雪，作为回报你可以教我什么呢？
>
> We can both learn from each other... I'll teach you to ski... and in return what can you teach me?

She said:

> 我没有什么特长
>
> I don't have any specialties.

So I was going to say:

> How about you cook for me and we'll call it even?

How would I say that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might say:
你给我做饭如何？这样我们就扯平了